# symfony + nginx

Tags: nginx, symfony

Установил я nginx, настроил виртуальные хосты. Но мне понадобилось залить symfony 5 запускать через CLI, но обращаться не через ip а допустим test.ru. В nginx в настройках виртуального хоста пишу, чтобы он слушал 9000 порт, но запускаю через symfony server:start на 9000 порту, symfony сервер запускается на 9001 порту или увеличивается на еденицу, тоесть запускается на следующем порту, якобы этот порт занят, если в настройках nginx убрать строку listen, symfony запускается на 9000 порту как и положено. Чего я не понимаю? что я делаю не так?

Comment: 1. Запускать внутренний сервер symfony стоит только ради отладки. Никогда на боевом сервере так не делайте. 2. В nginx вы настраиваете порт, по которому слушать запросы пользователей, а не порт который нужно проксировать (т.е. пробрасывать через себя данные которые крутятся на другом сервере)

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста, я настроил виртуальный хост test.ru на nginx указал директорию public проекта на symfony не запускал вебсервер symfony а тупо указал nginx где лежит index.php и он при обращении к test.ru пишет "file not found". Я не могу понять какого файла нет. В логах тоже не указанно какого файла нет. Я так понимаю мне уже бэкенд фреймворка пишет что файла нет а не nginx и.к. файл index.php есть.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы планируете запускать сервер силами самой симфони, то можете использовать вот такой конфиг для nginx:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    server_name test.ru;
    client_max_body_size 32M;

    location / {
        proxy_bind        $host:80;
        proxy_set_header  HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        port_in_redirect  off;
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

Суть в том, что nginx слушает 80 порт (http) и все запросы к сайту `test.ru` перенаправляет на `http://127.0.0.1:9000`. В `hosts` файле надо не забыть прописать

```
127.0.0.1 test.ru
```

ps. На боевом сервере лучше использовать `php-fpm`.

Comment: Ага вчера разобрался, но всеравно спасибо большое. Проблема была в сокете php7.3-fpm я указал не ту версию пхп. Сначала сделал чтобы работало как просто перенаправление портов, но вчера все-таки решил проблему чтобы не запускать сервер symfony а просто уже   nginx напрямую брал symfony.

Answer (score 0):

файл конфига получился такой

```
server {
listen 127.0.0.1:80; #слушаем определнноый ип адрес
server_name test.ru; #домен какой будет слушать
root /home/pc/dev_/bibi/public;  #корневая папка индекс.пхп
index index.php;
client_max_body_size 100m;  #максимальный размер тела запроса
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;  #чпу
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; #на каком адресе запущен прокси сервер на какой нужно перенаправить
    }
    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\.(?:ht|git|svn) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```